# Is is possible to intercept a static method on an object you don't own and did not create?

Tags: c#, proxy, aop, interceptor

Referring to my possible answer to this question: [How would you audit ASP.NET Membership tables, while recording what user made the changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907535/how-would-you-audit-asp-net-membership-tables-while-recording-what-user-made-the/2911616#2911616)

Is it possible to intercept a call, coming from code you do not own, to a ctor on a sealed internal class that you do not own with the intention of manipulating the object before returning?

Concrete example:

`SqlMembershipProvider`, for all of it's data access, instantiates a connection helper class, `System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder`.

The desired result is to intercept this instantiation and perform an operation on the public connection that is opened in the ctor of `System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder` before letting execution continue.

**UPDATE:**
So, as leppie observed regarding my example, what I say I want isn't what I want at all.

The target is now `System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection()`

So, can we intercept the call to this method?

```
internal static SqlConnectionHolder GetConnection(string connectionString, bool revertImpersonation)
```

Is this possible. If so, an brief example would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont think this is possible. From looking at the code in Reflector, it also seems difficult to get hold of the SqlConnection object being used.

Comment: @leppie - i may be missing something but I can get a reference `internal SqlConnection _Connection;` with my eyes closed and my mouth full, on a bad day. twice. Am I missing something? ;-)

Comment: poet: and how do you get hold of the `SqlConnectionHolder` instance?  From what I can see this is created freshly every time via the `SqlConnectionHelper` class.

Comment: @leppie - looks like i was missing something. ;-) Which leads to an updated question. Thanks for the reality check.

Answer (score 2):

Technically this is possible with an IL rewriter, similar to what Postsharp does.  However, given that this is a .NET assembly you're talking about that has a strong name, is stored in the GAC and ngen-ed, that isn't likely to ever get past the "technically possible" stage.

Comment: Hans - the question has changed a bit, thanks to leppie, but I suspect the answer is the same. So, although in this instance it is not possible, I would like to know more in general. Could you add a few good links? Or even better, add an expressly solicited search term that would point to the appropriate resources. Heres your chance to LMGTFY someone and not get dinged for it. ;-)

Comment: Not sure, most of it is closed source.  Perhaps AspectSharp: http://sourceforge.net/projects/aspectsharp/files/

Comment: Thanks for that. Have a + on me. Am going to bump this a few times to see what shakes out before accepting.